# @ExceptionHandler annotation in controller does not catching MaxUploadSizeExceededException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying a very straightforward thing - catching the **[MaxUploadSizeExceededException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MaxUploadSizeExceededException.html)** errors associated with file uploads.

Here's the relevant bit in my spring-servlet.xml :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</bean>
```

And here's the **@ExceptionHandler** method in the controller that also handles the file upload stuff

```
@ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
public String handleException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("uploadErrorMessage", e.getCause().getMessage());
    return "redirect:/page";
}
```

File upload is working fine. However, when I test with a file that exceeds the size limit - it throws the error, and the method for ExceptionHanler is never called.

Any help or pointers on what else to look for / at would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the ExceptionHandler to look for LimitExceededException and MultiPartException instead of the sub Exceptions?

Comment: i tried the both, but it doesn't work, it's seems to me that ExceptionHandler  in the controllers catch only exception fired in this controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a separate class with @ControllerAdvice this will then take care of exception coming from all controllers.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
public String handleException(MaxUploadSizeExceededException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("uploadErrorMessage", e.getCause().getMessage());
    return "redirect:/page";
}
}
```

Thus if we define our @ExceptionHandler annotation on method in @ControllerAdvice class, it will be applied to all the controllers.

You must define following in your spring-servlet.xml file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```